# Generating a password by switching letters

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Stefan creates a password by switching his names's letters two by two,getting the password "fanest".How many switches did he make?
I don't know how to approach this,I simply tried making a few switches by hand,but I doubt this helps.
EDIT: After the discussion in the comments, I believe that we need to find the minimum number of moves and "two by two" means blocks of two letters.

Comment: Does two by two mean  that he switches blocks of two letters at a time? For example, $STeFAn \to FAeSTn$ etc.

Comment: The answer is simple. We can't know. After Stefan got to fanest he could in theory make a switch and then make the same switch (therefore going back to fanest with 2 more switches). He can repeat this as many times as he like and he will still end up getting fanest again.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг the problem doesn't specify this,but I also think that it means he switches blocks of two letters(otherwise it wouldn't really make any sense to me at least)

Comment: @Yanko I agree with you,but once he gets to fanest he stops switching.

Comment: @MathGuy Same problem: he could go stefan -> tsefan -> stefan as many times as he liked before getting to fanest, for example. If we're aiming for the minimum number of switches needed, then stefan -> ftesan -> faestn -> fanste -> fanets -> fanest is five steps. Can there be a shorter one?

Comment: @user3482749 thanks for your input ! I thought about this one too and I guess there can't be a shorter one. However,the problem is ambiguous since they may want to say that "two by two" means blocks of two letters as another user observed above. What should we do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically generating the graph of all possible passwords achievable from 'stefan' by repeatedly swapping two blocks of two characters each produces $360$ distinct strings (half of the permutations of 'stefan'). The string 'fanest' is not among these strings.

Programmatically generating the graph of all possible passwords achievable from 'stefan' by repeatedly swapping two single characters produces $720$ distinct strings (all  of the permutations of 'stefan'). These strings require at most $5$ swaps. The string 'fanest' is among those strings that require $5$ swaps.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I would have coded it myself if I weren't hopeless at programming. Here is another thing I have just observed : 'fanest' cannot be achieved from 'stefan' by swapping two blocks of two characters because 'n' is on an odd position and it would have to get to an even one,which is impossible since we swap chunks of two characters.

Comment: @MathGuy Swapping 'te' with 'an' gives 'sanfte', with both 'a' and 'n' in target position. There is, however, as my answer suggests, some kind of parity with the block swaps.